# Writing mocha test for NodeJS express server API using Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, mocha.js, glob

I am currently on the process of writing integration test for a node js application I'm working on with my team.

However, I can't seem to figure how to proceed for testing the express server. The server is using redis-server for caching.

It seems that for my tests to succeed I should be running redis-server, and also running my app separately (via nodemon app), which doesn't make sense, as the tests should be independant of any external running commands.

When I run mocha test without running nodemon app, the application never gets into the glob function and I get:

```
  1) Deeplinq Server should return dubai search results via hippie:
     Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
      at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
      at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
```

You can have a look at the test I wrote

```
    var site = require('../app/lib/site.js');
    var hippie = require('hippie');
    var http = require('http');
    var sinon = require('sinon');
    var index = require('../app/index.js');
    var server = require('../app/server.js');
    var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Deeplinq', function () {

    describe('Server', function () {

 it("should return dubai search results via hippie", function (done) {
            hippie(server)
                .auth('user', 'user')
                .get('http://dsg.deeplinq.dev:3000/en/search?q=dubai')
                .expectStatus(200)
                .expectHeader('text/html; charset=utf-8')
                .end(function (err, res, body) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    done();
                })
        });
    });

});
```

And here's some parts the server.js file:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import hbs from 'express-hbs';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import glob from "glob";
import fs from "fs";
import _ from "lodash";
import Site from './lib/site';
import Vhost from './lib/vhost';
import winston from 'winston';
import expressWinston from 'express-winston';
//require('node-jsx').install({extension: '.jsx'});

require('winston-papertrail').Papertrail;
//import path from "path";
var REDIS_URL = process.env.REDIS_URL || 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
var MONGODB_URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'localhost/deeplinq';

var redis = require('redis').createClient(REDIS_URL, {return_buffers: true});
const server = express();
const ENV = ( process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development' );
const PROD = ( ENV==='production' );

var loggerTransports = [];

if (PROD && process.env.PAPERTRAIL_SERVER) {
    const trail = process.env.PAPERTRAIL_SERVER.split(':');
    loggerTransports.push(new winston.transports.Papertrail({
        program: 'deeplinq-ui',
        host: trail[0],
        port: trail[1],
        level: 'debug',
        colorize: true,
        json: false,
        meta: true
    }));
}else {
    loggerTransports.push(new winston.transports.Console({
        json: false,
        meta: true,
        colorize: true,
        level: 'debug'
    }));
}

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: loggerTransports,
    colorize: true,
    json: false,
    meta: true,
    level: 'debug'
});

logger.info('================================================');
logger.info('ENV : %s', ENV);
logger.info('================================================');

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Config
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

server.engine('hbs', hbs.express4({
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views'
}));
server.set('view engine', 'hbs');
server.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
server.use(expressWinston.logger({
    transports: loggerTransports,
    level: 'debug',
    meta: false, // optional: control whether you want to log the meta data about the request (default to true)
    //msg: "HTTP {{req.method}} {{req.url}}", // optional: customize the default logging message. E.g. "{{res.statusCode}} {{req.method}} {{res.responseTime}}ms {{req.url}}"
    expressFormat: false, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting, with the same colors. Enabling this will override any msg and colorStatus if true. Will only output colors on transports with colorize set to true
    colorStatus: true, // Color the status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red). Will not be recognized if expressFormat is true
    ignoreRoute: function (req, res) { return req.url.match(/(css|js|gz|png|gif|jpeg|jpg|woff|wotf|ttf|ico)/); } // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
}));


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Virtual hosts management
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

var vhost = new Vhost();


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Load sites
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

redis.on("connect", function () {


    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Bootstrap
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    server.use(vhost.vhost(server.enabled('trust proxy')));




    // Scan sites definitions (dl.json)


    glob("sites/**/dl.json", {}, function (er, files) {
        logger.info("= GLOB ===============================================");

        _.each(files, function (file) {
            var dl = require(path.resolve(file));
            var _env = dl.env;
            var props = require(path.resolve(path.join(path.dirname(file), 'views', 'props')));
            var env = _env.default;
            _.merge(env, _env[ENV]);

            logger.info('Registering: %s / %s', dl.id, dl.about);
            env.id = dl.id;
            env.REDIS_URL = REDIS_URL;

            _.each(env.dns, function (dns) {
                var context = dns.split('/');
                if (context.length>1) {
                    context = '/' + context[1]
                }else {
                    context = '/'
                }
                // TODO:ENHANCE: Create one Site per dl.json not per dns entry
                var site = new Site(context, env, props, path.dirname(file), redis, logger);
                vhost.register(dns, site.app);
                logger.info('Host registed: %s', dns);
                console.log("")
            })
        });
        server.use(expressWinston.errorLogger({transports: loggerTransports}));

        const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
        server.listen(port);
        logger.info("Server's listening on port %s", port);
        logger.info("================================================");
    });

});

export default server;
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction ? What am I doing wrong, what can I do to fix these issues ?

Comment: Well, in your `server.js` you've got: `redis.on("connect", function () {`, and all the scanning happens inside. How do you imagine the scanning will happen **without** running the redis server? :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov Even when running redis-server, I Get `Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED` the glob function is never accessed.

Comment: Well add error handler on redis client: `client.on("error", function (err) {`

Comment: @AndreyPopov Adding an error handler did nothing.. I'm thinking maybe it's got to do with async execution of glob function... Why is it never accessed ?